# how do you convert a number in a text form to a number?

Tags: java, string, integer

What is the code wherein if you input any number in text form line for example "twenty seven" the output is 27?

but with this code it will take time to make it reach like in millions that is why I want to know what can be done to make things efficient

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class conversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter A Number In Text Form: ");
            String inp = input.nextLine();

        if (inp.equals("zero")) { 
            System.out.println("0");
        } else if (inp.equals("one")) {
            System.out.println("1");
        } else if (inp.equals("two")) {
            System.out.println("2"); 
        } else if (inp.equals("three")) {
            System.out.println("3");
        } else if (inp.equals("four")) {
            System.out.println("4");
        } else if (inp.equals("five")) {
            System.out.println("5");
        } else if (inp.equals("six")) {
            System.out.println("6");
        } else if (inp.equals("seven")) {
            System.out.println("7");
        } else if (inp.equals("eight")) {
            System.out.println("8");
        } else if (inp.equals("nine")) {
            System.out.println("9");

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I already added  my code

Comment: This is not JavaScript code.  I suggest removing the JavaScript tag   Java is to JavaScript like pen is to penguin.

Comment: Well this question requires effort. You will have to define 1 to 19 separately and then 20 to ... separately. Refer this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-number-to-words/

Answer (score 0):

create a dictionary map with all possible but minimal combinations : 
e.g var dics= { twenty :20 , two: 2}

Now you can split your input string by space. and then try to build a logic to utilize these values.

this will be complex to implement for sure but yes , it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string to an array with `split` function.
and loop it

```java
String[] inps = inp.split(" ");
int remaining = inps.length;
String outstr = "";
for (String numstr : inps) 
{
   remaining--;
   int digit = 0;
   switch (numstr.toLowerCase()) // in the JDK7, You can use Strings in switch 
   {
   case "twenty": outstr += '2'; digit=10; break;
   case "thirty": outstr += '3'; digit=10; break;
   // ...
   }
   if (digit == 10 && remaining == 0)
   {
      // tenth digit, but no remaining
      outstr += '0';
   }
}
System.out.println(outstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
public static final String[] tens = { 
  "",   // 0
  "",  // 1
  "Twenty",  // 2
  "Thirty",  // 3
  "Forty",  // 4
  "Fifty",  // 5
  "Sixty",  // 6
  "Seventy", // 7
  "Eighty",  // 8
  "Ninety"  // 9
};

public static String convert(final int n) {
 if (n < 0) {
  return "Minus " + convert(-n);
 }

 if (n < 20) {
  return units[n];
 }

 if (n < 100) {
  return tens[n / 10] + ((n % 10 != 0) ? " " : "") + units[n % 10];
 }

 if (n < 1000) {
  return units[n / 100] + " Hundred" + ((n % 100 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 100);
 }

 if (n < 100000) {
  return convert(n / 1000) + " Thousand" + ((n % 10000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 1000);
 }

 if (n < 10000000) {
  return convert(n / 100000) + " Lakh" + ((n % 100000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 100000);
 }

 return convert(n / 10000000) + " Crore" + ((n % 10000000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 10000000);
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {

 int n;
 Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number to convert into word format");
 n =s.nextInt();
 System.out.println(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(n) + "='" + convert(n) + "'");

}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted it in eclipse but it has errors how do i fix it?